Get Image Co-ordinates of Target Image with Hololens 2
I want to extract Image co-ordinated from the Hololens 2 with respect to the camera co-ordinates. We can easily get the spatial co-ordinates with this. But I need camera co-ordinates which are raw and without applying the spatial mapping from the Vuforia library.
When tracking a target we get co-ordinates they are related to the image in the world position. I have check the library and part of execution but not able to find where they apply the camera co-ordinate to spatial co-ordinate transformation.

Are you using Unity?

Information about the Vuforia spatial frames of reference is available here for Unity
https://developer.vuforia.com/library/device-tracking/spatial-frame-reference
and here for native
https://developer.vuforia.com/library/device-tracking/spatial-frame-reference-native
To get the pose of the target in the camera reference frame you have to combine the pose you get from the target observer (which transforms points from Target to World coordinates) with the rendering view matrix (or the inverse of the device tracker pose).
In native code one would do something like this
// get the target pose
VuPoseInfo targetPoseInfo; 
vuObservationGetPoseInfo(observer, &targetPoseInfo);
    
// get the render state
VuRenderState renderState;
vuStateGetRenderState(state, &renderState);

// combine the view matrix with the target pose
auto targetInCameraPose = vuMatrix44FMultiplyMatrix(renderState.viewMatrix, targetPoseInfo.pose);

